# asp net identity EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am having a problem with "cache" in asp .net identity, when I change password, name, any claim, I must restart the application for validate the changes.

I have this in SecurityContext

```
public class SecurityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public SecurityContext()
        : base("Db")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("security");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("_Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("_Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .ToTable("_UsersRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("_UsersClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .ToTable("_UsersLogins");
    }
}
```

Login:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _PublicClientId;
    private readonly Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> _UserManagerFactory;
    private readonly Func<RoleManager<IdentityRole>> _RoleManagerFactory;

    #region Constructors
    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId,
        Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> userManagerFactory,
        Func<RoleManager<IdentityRole>> roleManagerFactory
        )
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        _PublicClientId = publicClientId;

        if (userManagerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userManagerFactory");
        _UserManagerFactory = userManagerFactory;

        if (roleManagerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("roleManagerFactory");
        _RoleManagerFactory = roleManagerFactory;

    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region GrantResourceOwnerCredentials
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (var userManager = _UserManagerFactory())
        {
            using (var roleManager = _RoleManagerFactory())
            {
                var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
                // Start Login success
                var oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                var cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                // Claims
                cookiesIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(XpClaimTypes.Application, _SessionData.ApplicationName));
                // Properties
                var properties = CreateProperties(user, roleManager);
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
                context.Validated(ticket);
                context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
                // End Login success
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion GrantResourceOwnerCredentials
}
```

obviating others methods

For example the method for changePassword:

```
    #region Password
    [HttpPut]
    [Authorize(Roles = AccountRoles.Superadministrador + "," + AccountRoles.Administrador)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Password(SetPasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var identity = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync((Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Name);
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);

        if (!(
            (identity.Roles.Any(x => x.Role.Name == AccountRoles.Superadministrador) && user.Roles.Any(x => x.Role.Name == AccountRoles.Administrador)) ||
            (identity.Roles.Any(x => x.Role.Name == AccountRoles.Administrador) && user.Roles.Any(x => x.Role.Name == AccountRoles.Usuario))
        ))
            throw new AuthenticationException();

        // Delete password
        {
            var result = await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(model.Id);
            var errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);
            if (errorResult != null)
                return errorResult;
        }

        // Add password
        {
            var result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(model.Id, model.Password);
            var errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);
            if (errorResult != null)
                return errorResult;
        }

        return Ok();
    }
    #endregion Password
```

There are the steps I followed:

- Login application
- Change the password
- Logout application
- Login with the new password (in table is changed, is correctly the change)
- Error with password
- Login with older password (the old password in table is not exists)
- Login successful
- Restart application
- The new password now is valid

The same problem is occurred when I change any value in BBDD of asp .net identity

Any Idea please?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your problem. Can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: There are the steps I followed:

Login application
Change the password
Logout application
Login with the new password (in table is changed, is correctly the change)
Error with password
Login with older password (the old password in table is not exists)
Login successful
Restart application
The new password now is valid

There are the steps I followed

Comment: so you are saying that after password change, you can login with the old password and new password only works after the application restart?

Comment: Yes, just right, trailmax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly I add the same issue because one of the contexts was being persisted and the other recreated on every call.

If you check one will not have the correct value from the DB, probably `ApplicationOAuthProvider`.

Try recreating the context for every call on the `ApplicationOAuthProvider`.

Comment: That sounds very plausible!

Comment: I am trying your response, is probable you have right, +1